# IAM Policy variable for Cognito groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

My situation is this:

I'm trying to control access to an S3 bucket using unix-like home directories via AWS Cognito. These home directories should be accessible by groups of users rather than each individual user. i.e.:

```
s3-bucket/home/group1  
s3-bucket/home/group2
s3-bucket/home/group3
```

When creating roles separately with group information (group name currently used as part of directory name for wildcarding), similar to [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/),  it works. However, I'd rather not make a separate IAM role for each group.

Before I used the enhanced flow I could restrict the role with a further policy via the `assumeRoleWithWebIdentity` call with STS. However when using just cognito, it expects only a role to apply.

Instead of directly applying a policy to the subject of the ID token (like `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}`), I'd rather have it use the group (like from `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:cognito:groups}`), such that I don't have to create a role for each new group, and the variable itself would help define the resource scope.

Has anyone had much luck with this? Or using string arrays/sets in IAM resource definitions in general? I was trying to do something like

`{"Fn::Select": [0, "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:cognito:groups}"]}`

but cloudformation complains about

`Template error: Fn::Select requires a list argument with two elements: an integer index and a list`.

Thanks!

P.S. I see [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazoncognitoidentity.html) which states that there are no service-specific keys for cognito for use in policies, but that doesn't seem right as I've seen people use `sub` `aud` `amr` etc in policies in other examples on the web, although a definitive guide doesn't seem well documented.

Comment: Any chance you found a solution for this?

Comment: Nah, I just passed in group information to my cfn in to help the condition, and use a role per group. I am doing something like `ForAnyValue:StringEquals` with roles checking saml groups for an IAM IdP route... but with cognito IdP's I couldn't find a good corollary